# Disable a Category in Magento pragramatically

Tags: magento

I am trying to disable a category in magento via code, I am not a coder, can someone help me please, I got the below from another post

```
<?php
$catId = 555;
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load( $catId );
$cat->setData('is_active', 0);
$cat->save();
```

Comment: How many categories do you want to disable?  Is this a one-off bulk update or part of an API call for example?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is the way to disabled a category problematically, have you tried?
what's issue now?